# PHP looping through array values in a query

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I'm attempting to loop through an array and use the rows(values) as the conditions for my SQL query but I can't seem to get it loop through the rows.  It only outputs the data for the first row where the `form_name = ' V243823'` then stops.  i need all the rows, so 3 arrays total to be returned.

> Campus Forms Array

```
[0] => Array
        (

            [PQ_Lookup] => V243823
            [RL_Lookup] => B3823RL
            [MA_Lookup] => F356823
        )
```

### Query

```
    foreach( $campus_forms[0] as $key => $row )
    {
    $this->db->select('form_deadline,form_url,form_fullname'); 
    $this->db->from('form_deadlines');

    $this->db->where('form_name', $row);
        $query = $this->db->get();

         if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                $campus_forms = $query->result_array();
                  return $campus_forms;
            }
      }
```

Comment: You're returning after you get through the first foreach, which exits the function. You probably want to append/merge that result to another array instead.

Comment: so something like `$new_forms = array();
array_push($new_forms, $campus_forms);` would that be best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first loop you are returning for this reason it doesn't execute next loop.Please return your data after foreach loop.You can hold your data in an array in every loop.You can do it in this way:

```
$form_data_array = array();

foreach( $campus_forms[0] as $key => $row )
    {
    $this->db->select('form_deadline,form_url,form_fullname'); 
    $this->db->from('form_deadlines');

    $this->db->where('form_name', $row);
        $query = $this->db->get();

         if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                $campus_forms = $query->result_array();
                 // return $campus_forms;
$form_data_array[] = $campus_forms;
            }
      }
return $form_data_array;
```